# How to express that "something is not right" with a friendship

Tags: phrase-requests, english-to-japanese

I'm a 1st year senior highschool student in Japan and have lived here for about two years.

Sometimes when I'm with my friends they don't talk or look at me as if I don't exist and I ask myself if I did something wrong. I've always been nice to them even up to this day. So that's why I asked one of my friends if I did something wrong to him/them in the past (and if I did I would be willing to say sorry).

He asked my why I was asking this kind of question and said that I'm just misunderstanding. So I want to say to him "Something doesn't really feel right at all". What would be the best way to express this in Japanese?

Comment: Also, we usually require to give your own translation attempt. You can see if a search in a phrase dictionary (e.g. http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=not+feel+right) already answers your question.

Comment: @Earthliŋ Argh you beat me to the edit.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some options:

> 変な雰囲気を感じる。(I feel a strange atmosphere)
>   空気が読みにくい。(The atmosphere is hard to read)
>   何かおかしい。(Something is wrong)